# Different SHA256 checksum of same version of ssh binary on different machines

Tags: ssh, sha, integrity, sha256

I was wondering if I compare SHA-256 of two binaries with same version on different machines, results will be two identical checksums.

I tried this on ssh on macOS (Catalina). (I checked that `ssh -V` produce exactly same version)

And tested with this command:

```
shasum -a 256 /usr/bin/ssh
```

and run same command on my friends macOS (Big Sur). But at the end I got two different results. Is this normal or I'm missing something?

Comment: Even if the same source code was used, it doesn't mean the binary is the same (e.g. different version of an underlying library, build timestamp, etc)

Comment: You are not missing any thing, they are two different binaries of the same program, specially on Macos they recompile for specific versions of the code because they in general have different syscalls and different code base. Do a test by copy the binary of our friend on the other host and do the sha operation.

Answer (score 3):

The SSH version alone does not say anything. The build can be different. Even a recompile with a different compiler versions, different compiler options or maybe a different time can lead to changes. But in this case the change is much bigger and more obvious:

On Mac OS Catalina (19.6.0) the ssh binary has a size of 2142352 bytes and `file` reports *Mach-O 64 bit executable x86_64* as architecture. On MacOS bigSur (20.1.0) the binary has a size of 4303584 and is an universal binary with support for *x86_64* and *arm64e*. Because the size differs also the content differs and thus the hash differs.

Note that the version is the same (OpenSSH 8.1p1) on both systems.

Comment: This is incorrect. Assuming a proper implementation, math is math and the resultant hash computation will not very with the machine architecture or OS. This is intrinsic to all digital forensic evaluations. It doesn't matter who is ruuning the hash check or on what machine, if the target file is identical the hash is identical.

Comment: @user10216038: huh? This question is not about computing the hash for the same input on different platforms. These files  have on different platforms obviously different size, different content and thus will result in a different hash.

Comment: Apparently we are talking at cross purposes. I'm not talking about hashing the SSH program. The OP was comparing the sha-256 hash of two **unknown** binary programs.

Comment: @user10216038: the OP was specifically running `shasum -a 256 /usr/bin/ssh`. And `/use/bin/ssh` is a different file on both OS. Note the OP is asking not about same file on two machines but about *"two binaries with same __version__"*

Comment: AH, my mistake! I didn't read the example as a **literal** comparison. I thought it was a quick shorthand example as the test said *I compare SHA-256 of two binaries with same version on different machines ...* I took that to mean generic not literal.

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities:

- Your computers have different architectures
- You are running the same version but different builds of ssh

A different build could mean different flags were used when compiling or the time they were compiled was different.

Hash checking is important for verifying the integrity of the same file, usually when transferring. It isn't useful for checking software from multiple sources.

Answer (score 0):

The same hash algorithm, SHA-256 in this case, should produce the same result regardless of the machine and OS.

In this case, I suspect that you are not looking at the **same file**. It might seem to be the same version level, but that's not the same file. It only takes a single bit difference to get a radically different hash result.

Take a copy of your file to his machine, or vice-versa, and re-run the hash check.